# When I add a new row, it overwrites the last I added

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using PHPExcel to load an Excel (xlsx) file into my html page.

I manage to add a new form using the form below, but unfortunately every single row I add it overwrite the first one. Is there a way to refresh so that I won't overwrite the previous added value?

Here is my form for adding a new row:

```
<form action="" method="post" id="AddForm" name="AddForm">
<input type="text" id="company" name="company" value="Enter new name" />
<input type="submit" id="save" name="add" value="add"/>
</form>
```

Below is the code I use to load / display / add a new row

```
    <?php

    require_once '../inc/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel.php';
    require_once '../inc/phpexcel/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php';
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("myExcelFile.xlsx");
    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();

    //add the new row
    $num_rows = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestRow();
    $objWorksheet->insertNewRowBefore($num_rows + 1, 1);
    $name = isset($_POST['name']) ? $_POST['name'] : '';
    if($submit){
//SAVING THE NEW ROW - on the last position in the table
    $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$num_rows+1,$name);
    }

    //display the table
    echo '<table>'."\n";
    echo '<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Company Name</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>'."\n";
    echo '<tbody>'."\n";
    foreach ($objWorksheet->getRowIterator() as $row) {
    echo '<tr>'."\n";
    $cellIterator = $row->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(false);
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
    echo '<td>'.$cell->getValue().'</td>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</tr>'."\n";
    }
    echo '</tbody>'."\n";
    echo '</table>'."\n";
    ?>
```

Comment: So where is the code used to save a new row? Does the `myExcelFile.xlsx` file get updated when you save a new row?

Comment: I don't see any writing of the workbook back to file here at all, is there more code that you're not showing?

Comment: @Mihai Todor: $objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$num_rows+1,$name);
save the line at the position wanted.

Comment: @Mark Baker: I just need to save it on the page not back in the book.

Comment: You'll have to keep track of all the new rows that you add in HTML then, because the PHP isn't persisted between calls... each time you add the new row in HTML and then execute the PHP it reloads the Excel file as it was when you first loaded the page

Comment: I guess I need to save the new addition into the file before performing another add. Otherwise my new changes will get lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution:
Inside the loop there is a need to save the file after each request:

```
$objWorksheet->setCellValueByColumnAndRow(0,$num_rows+1,$company_name);
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('myExcelFile.xlsx');
echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";
```